# new line in string text

Tags: php, html

So i'm making something and i dont know how to make new line in php i've tried using `nl2br` but its giving me `Template Error`

[image: Error]

This is how it looks without new line

[image]

it says

```
Cadilab
AdministratorOnline
```

and it should be

```
Cadilab Administrator
Online
```

This is the code:

```
    echo '
<div id="profileview">
    <div class="cat_bar">
        <h3 class="catbg">
            <span class="ie6_header floatleft"><img src="', $settings['images_url'], '/icons/profile_sm.gif" alt="" class="icon" />', $txt['summary'], '</span>
        </h3>
    </div>

    <div class="covernebitno">
    <div class="avatar-profil"><a href="/index.php?action=profile">', $context['member']['avatar']['image'], '</a></center></div>
        <div class="usercover">
<div class="informacije">

<p>'.$context['member']['name'].'</br><span class="bojeipticice">'.nl2br((!empty($context['member']['group']) ? $context['member']['group'] : $context['member']['post_group']). '\r\n' .$context['member']['online']['text']) .'</p>
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/U0TijfL.jpg" />

    <div class="covernebitno">

    </div></div>

            ';
```

Comment: `,` need to be changed from `.`

Comment: `<p>'.$context['member']['name'].'</br><span class="bojeipticice">'.nl2br((!empty($context['member']['group']) ? $context['member']['group'] : $context['member']['post_group']).'\r\n'.$context['member']['online']['text']) .'</p>`

Comment: its like this now http://i.imgur.com/BqGhyre.jpg\

Comment: Is this a string or being echoed? (I'm not looking at images)

Comment: echoed full code: http://pastebin.com/8bcxU2ME

Comment: Include code on this site, not other places. The question will be useless if other sites dont exist in the future.

Comment: Which variable has `Cadilab
AdministratorOnline`?

Comment: <p>.... but somehow i got it working with </br> thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this code, you can either use `<br/><br/>`:

```
<p>' . $context['member']['name'] . '</br><span class="bojeipticice">' . nl2br((!empty($context['member']['group']) ? $context['member']['group'] : $context['member']['post_group']) . '<br/><br/>' . $context['member']['online']['text']) . '</p>
```

OR use `"\r\n"` (enclosed with double quotes, instead of `'\r\n'`):

```
<p>' . $context['member']['name'] . '</br><span class="bojeipticice">' . nl2br((!empty($context['member']['group']) ? $context['member']['group'] : $context['member']['post_group']) . "\r\n" . $context['member']['online']['text']) . '</p>
```

Comment: But the answer to me above from Anant doesnt give me errors but it gives me this http://i.imgur.com/BqGhyre.jpg

Comment: Commas work with echo, http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php. `echo 'this is', 'valid';` https://eval.in/522324

Comment: @Nathaniel Edited code to remove the comma at the start and end, I believe you do already have an open quote and close quote which is not shown in the screenshot.

Comment: Yes but it doesnt give me new line, it stays like this http://i.imgur.com/BqGhyre.jpg
full code: http://pastebin.com/8bcxU2ME

Comment: @Nathaniel Maybe use `<br/><br/>` instead?

Comment: @Nathaniel I've tried your code and it would work if `"\r\n"` is enclosed with double quotes.

Comment: Solution given is missing single quotes at the beginning and end of each echo.

Comment: @JamesWiley Yup, I know, his code already has the single quotes at the start and end